# Reparent Attachments from Email record to parent Case Record following EmailtoCase

Tags: apex, email2case

Whilst the question of how has been asked and answered numerous times and indeed we have implemented the solution to clone the Attachment record.

My question is concerning the deletion of the Attachment record that is parented by the source Object - in this case the Email.

All other solutions suggest that the original Attachment record must be deleted, however in our case we would still like to see the attachments related to the original email as well as the Case. i.e. NOT deleting the original Attachment record

At present we can not find any issue with this but I was wondering if the community had any insight as to the impact of a file being attached to two objects? for example and primarily is Storage affected (duplicated).

If not, happy days. just wanted to see if anyone had come across this before

thanks

Ben

Comment: Assuming you only to view all the attachments associated to the case and emailMessages, Building an inline VF page on the case to show the attachments from Case and the associated EmailMessages might be useful. This way you will not duplicate the attachments, no reparenting etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is very little metadata on an Attachment that is editable (the title and description), it seems as if your issues would be

- Duplicate storage (if your customers send you big log files as attachments in Email2Case)
- Possibility that a tech support agent chooses to retitle/describe the attachment in one place but not the other leading to confusion